# Regex causing website not to display on mobile?

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, mobile-website

i have a website written with vuejs and hosted by firebase. yesterday i managed to narrow down an issue where the site would simply display a blank white page on mobile devices, and it comes down to these two objects i have declared in one of my component's data function:

```
re: {
    youtube: /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*)/,
    id: /(?<=\?v=)\w*(?=[^#\&\?]*)/,
    //for timestamp at end of youtube urls
    urlTimestamp: /(?<=&t=)((?:[0-9]{1,2})h)?((?:[0-9]{1,3})m)?((?:[0-9]{1,5})s)?/g,
    // for checking if timestamp string is valid
    timestamp: /^([0-9]{1,2}h)?([0-9]{1,3}m)?([0-9]{1,5}s)?$/g,
},
rules: {
    name: [
        v => !!v || 'Required'
    ],
    url: [
        v => !v || v && /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*)/.test(v) || 'Invalid URL',
        v => !v || /(?<=\?v=)([^#\&\?]*)/.test(v) && v.match(/(?<=\?v=)([^#\&\?]*)/)[0].length === 11 || 'Video ID must be 11 characters'
    ],
    timestamp: [
        v => !v || v && (/^([0-9]{1,2}h)?([0-9]{1,3}m)?([0-9]{1,5}s)?$/g).test(v) || 'Invalid format',
    ],
},
```

(there are two timestamp regexes because one pulls the timestamp from the end of a youtube url and the other checks if a timestamp string by itself is valid)

when i delete them both, the website displays fine. deleting just one or the other results in the same white page. using regexes in the 'watch' functions for this component also causes this same error. i have no idea what the problem here could be.

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out. [safari currently does not support lookbehind regexes](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind). i don't know why this causes the entire site to not display, but i removed the lookbehind part and it all works now.